# Adding Image into Button in Java Script

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, p5.js

I need to make a image clickable(button) or add a image to a button.

Here is the code that i want to modify

```
class Button{
    constructor(){
      this.button1 = createButton("Test");
      }
 
    display(){
      this.button1.position(displayWidth - 1150, displayHeight/2 - 300);
      this.button1.size(125.6,183.3);
      }
    
    this.button1.mousePressed(()=>{
      console.log("Worked!!");
  });
```

I am making in visual studio code and i have the p5 play and p5.js library.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set css style property by [`style()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Element/style). For instance set the "background" property:

```js
button.style('background', "url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Rabbid76/graphics-snippets/master/resource/texture/apple64.png)");
```

```js
let button;
function setup() {
    createCanvas(100, 100);
    background(0);
    button = createButton("Test");
    button.style('color', "white");
    button.style('background', "url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Rabbid76/graphics-snippets/master/resource/texture/apple64.png)");
    button.style('width', "64px");
    button.style('height', "64px");
    button.position(19, 19);
    button.mousePressed(buttonPressed);
}

function buttonPressed() {
    button.style('background', "url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Rabbid76/graphics-snippets/master/resource/texture/banana64.png)");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.0.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```